# What's the new user menu in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

My Chrome recently updated and now there's a new profile switcher thingie and I don't think I like it.

[image]

Can I remove it?

Answer (score 3):

Chrome recently launched a new update to the profile switching UI on desktop Chrome.  Here are some of the potential advantages of the new UI:

- Improved profile experience for multiple people sharing the same computer
- Guest mode on desktop Chrome, increasing your privacy when you let a friend on your computer
- More visible sign-in indication and transparency into browser state

Chrome says "There’s still polishing left to do, and we’re working hard to satisfy as many workflows as possible."

### Profile switching takes longer?

If you're finding that profile switching now takes an extra action, there are some opportunities.  On mac and ubuntu-unity, you can switch profiles via the “People” menu in the toolbar in two clicks.  Chrome indicates there are more improvements on the way for all platforms, but a fix for now is enabling the fast-user-switching flag in Chrome experiments:

1. Go to chrome://flags
2. Search for enable-fast-user-switching
3. Enable this flag, and restart your browser

This will put a list of profiles in the drop-down menu.

### Yellow triangle next to profile name?

[image]

If you're seeing a yellow triangle next to your profile name, then it means there's an error in the Account Sync.  Click into it and you can re-authenticate with your password so that Chrome is signed in with your Google account. (There's [a few benefits](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/signin.html) of that)  That will take care of the yellow triangle and get your Chrome back to a happy state.

Comment: +1 for explaining the yellow triangle which I first saw today even though the little menu has been there for a while now.